# How to solve this simple PHP forloop issue?

Tags: php

Here is the content of my flat file database:

```
Jacob | Little | 22 | Male | Web Developer *
Adam | Johnson | 45 | Male | President *
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php

$fopen = fopen('db.txt', 'r');

if (!$fopen) { echo 'File not found'; }

$fread = fread($fopen, filesize('db.txt'));

$records = explode('|', $fread);

?>

<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <thead>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>Occupation</th>
        </thead>
    </tr>
    <?php

    $rows = explode('*', $fread);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($rows) - 1; $i++)
    {

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$records[0].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$records[1].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$records[2].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$records[3].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$records[4].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    fclose($fopen);

    ?>
</table>
```

Problem is I am getting the output of the first record repeated twice instead of 2 records one for Jacob and one for Adam. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the `|` explode inside the loop:

```
$rows = explode('*', $fread);
for($i = 0; $i < count($rows) - 1; $i++)
{
    $records = explode('|', $rows[$i]);

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$records[0].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$records[1].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$records[2].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$records[3].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$records[4].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

even better rewrite the `for` loop as:

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
{
    $records = explode('|', $row);

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$records[0].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$records[1].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$records[2].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$records[3].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$records[4].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the for loop variable `$i` being used inside the loop? Typo?

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting the same records array twice.

`$records` doesn't change

You're going about this backwards, split the rows first, then foreach over the exploded row.

ex.

```
$rows = explode('*',$fread);

foreach($rows as $row) {
    //print each row
    $row_array = explode('|', $row);

    $row_array[0];
    $row_array[1];
    //... etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're splitting the contents of the *entire* file by calling `explode`; `$records` will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Jacob 
    [1] =>  Little 
    [2] =>  22 
    [3] =>  Male 
    [4] =>  Web Developer *
Adam 
    [5] =>  Johnson 
    [6] =>  45 
    [7] =>  Male 
    [8] =>  President *
)
```

So in each of the iterations in your loop, you're simply printing elements 0-4 in this array. What you should be doing is splitting the file into lines, then exploding each line individually. The easiest way to do this is to use the [`file`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function:

```
$lines = file('db.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    $record = explode('|', $line);

    // Display the record info.
}
```

Here, `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` tells `file` not to include the new line characters in each array element. This way, you no longer need the `*` at the end of each record (which I presume is there to delimit records).